# Logstash doc_as_upsert cross index in Elasticsearch to eliminate duplicates

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a logstash configuration that uses the following in the output block in an attempt to mitigate duplicates.

```
output {
        if [type] == "usage" {
                elasticsearch {
                        hosts => ["elastic4:9204"]
                        index => "usage-%{+YYYY-MM-dd-HH}"
                        document_id => "%{[@metadata][fingerprint]}"
                        action => "update"
                        doc_as_upsert => true
                }

        }
}
```

The fingerprint is calculated from a SHA1 hash of two unique fields.

This works when logstash sees the same doc in the same index, but since the command that generates the input data doesn't have a reliable rate at which different documents appear, logstash will sometimes insert duplicates docs in a different date stamped index.

For example, the command that logstash runs to get the input generally returns the last two hours of data. However, since I can't definitively tell when a doc will appear/disappear, I tun the command every fifteen minutes.

This is fine when the duplicates occur within the same hour. However, when the hour or day date stamp rolls over, and the document still appears, elastic/logstash thinks it's a new doc.

Is there a way to make the upsert work cross index? These would all be the same type of doc, they would simply apply to every index that matches "usage-*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new index is an entirely new keyspace and there's no way to tell ES to not index two documents with the same ID in two different indices.

However, you could prevent this by adding an [`elasticsearch` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html) to your pipeline which would look up the document in all indices and if it finds one, it could drop the event.

Something like this would do (note that `usages` would be an alias spanning all `usage-*` indices):

```
filter {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elastic4:9204"]
        index => "usages"
        query => "_id:%{[@metadata][fingerprint]}"
        fields => {"_id" => "other_id"}
    }
    # if the document was found, drop this one
    if [other_id] {
        drop {}
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that the load on the cluster increased by quite a bit after putting this in place. But so far it appears to be working!

Comment: Yes, because now for every event that goes through Logstash, a query is made against your ES to verify whether the event already exists or not.

Comment: In an attempt to reduce the search space, I added a ruby filter to get yesterday's date. I'm only worried about dupes that could appear when the index name rolls over to the next day. However, it appears that in the elasticsearch filter, it doesn't expand fields:

        `elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["fmyelastic04.fm.intel.com:9204"]
                index => 'monitoring-cama-usage-"%{[@metadata][yesterday]}"'
                query => "_id:%{[@metadata][fingerprint]}"
                fields => {"_id" => "id_found"}
        }`

Comment: HI @anthozep, In my case request get publish to yesterday index and reponse get publish to today index. So I wanted to correlate the request and response in yesterday index. any suggestion?