# Logstash elasticsearch filter, variable index name

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a configuration that attempts to reduce duplicates by querying my cluster for an existing id, then dropping the field if it exists. The reason for this is that events that are ingested can sometimes be found in the input on multiple runs, so while using fingerprint works for indices of the same name, when the hour or day rolls over, the duplicates are inserted.

Val gave me a great answer here: [Logstash doc_as_upsert cross index in Elasticsearch to eliminate duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070865/logstash-doc-as-upsert-cross-index-in-elasticsearch-to-eliminate-duplicates) but I noticed incresed load on the cluster.

I'm trying to reduce the search space, and therefore, the load by just looking in the previous hour's index name, instead of all indices that match a name.

Here is the relevant filter code:

```
filter {
        fingerprint {
                method => "SHA1"
                key => "uniq"
                source => ["ID"]
                target => "[@metadata][fingerprint]"
        }
        ruby {
                init => "require 'time'"
                code => '
                begin;
                event.set("Yesterday", Time.at(Time.now.to_i - (60 * 60 * 24)).utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
                end'
        }
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["elastic04:9204"]
                index => "usage-%{Yesterday}"
                query => "_id:%{[@metadata][fingerprint]}"
                fields => {"_id" => "id_found"}
        }
        if [id_found] {
                drop {}
        }
}
```

The problem is that it appears that the elasticsearch filter plugin does not expand variables in the index name. Here is the error:

```
[2016-12-13T11:34:02,659][WARN ][logstash.filters.elasticsearch] Failed to query elasticsearch for previous event {:index=>"usage-%{Yesterday}", :query=>"_id:e6fdc447a1d72b2fcf41d05b72de9df0160014b6", :event=>2016-12-13T19:34:00.933Z elastic04 %{message}, :error=>#<Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound: [404] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"usage-%{Yesterday}","index":"usage-%{Yesterday}"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"usage-%{Yesterday}","index":"usage-%{Yesterday}"},"status":404}>}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the square brackets, i.e. `event.set("Yesterday"...` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried putting the 'yesterday' data in @metadata as well. I can see that the field gets the correct data, but it doesn't expand in the index field. Let me edit my question to add the error.

Comment: Can you comment out the `elasticsearch` filter and add an `stdout` output. Do you see the field `Yesterday` in the event that is output?

Comment: Yes, I also tried it in @metadata and it was present in stdout